# KVM: Unable to cut/paste between ubuntu host and windows 10 guest

Tags: ubuntu, clipboard, linux-kvm

host: ubuntu 19.04

Guest: Windows 10

I have Installed the latest version of spice-guest-tools and qemu-ga-x86_64 in the guest OS. The clipboard works with other guests. It does not work with this particular guest.

Bases on my reading cut+paste between host and guest should work, but it does not. Any ideas how to fix or debug. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me, ***however my host is Ubuntu 18.04***:

1. Started and logged into the Windows 10 guest.
2. Using Google Chrome on the guest I downloaded ***spice-guest-tools-latest.exe*** by clicking on the following link: https://www.spice-space.org/download/windows/spice-guest-tools/spice-guest-tools-latest.exe
3. Installed ***spice-guest-tools-latest.exe*** on Windows 10.

Copy and paste worked immediately after the installation.

The following probably needs to be set on the host for the specific Windows 10 guest:

[HostGuestChannelSpice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnMFg.jpg)